# Why is a AD Domain controller object set to "unconstrained delegation"? Can this be altered?

Tags: active-directory, security, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, delegation

As part of identifying accounts with "unconstrained Delegation" , it came to our notice that all domain controllers are configured that way.

Can i change "unconstrained delegation" setting on all domain controllers in the org? what would break if i do so?

Answer (score 1):

"Domain Controllers, by default, are configured with unconstrained delegation."

- https://blog.stealthbits.com/what-is-kerberos-delegation-an-overview-of-kerberos-delegation/